# Deploy Gitlab Spring Boot project on Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, heroku, deployment

I have Spring Boot project. After I created Heroku acc and new app. I changed my Postresql properties in application.properties, but the problem is deploying. If I am not mistaken, I cannot link gitlab with heroku, but can link with github. So, I'd like to know if I need to move my project on github or there are some ways to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to move your code to GitHub. There are [several ways to deploy to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deployment), only one of which is dependent on GitHub.

One common method would be to [simply push your code to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git). Assuming you already have the Heroku CLI installed:

1. [Add a new remote called `heroku` that points to Heroku's Git repository for your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#for-an-existing-app). The easiest way to do that is to run

   ```bash
   heroku git:remote -a example-app
   ```

   from your project directory. If you inspect your remotes you should see a new one called `heroku`.
2. [Then `git push` to the new `heroku` remote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploy-your-code). In the common scenario where you want to deploy your local `main` or `master` branch, it's as simple as running

   ```bash
   git push heroku main  # or "master"
   ```

   If you are deploying from another branch [you'll still have to push to `main` or `master` on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploy-from-a-branch-besides-main). Only those two branch names trigger a build.

I engourage you to read through all of the links I have provided above. Heroku's documentation for this stuff is quite good.